# how to vary splitter height dynamically in kendoUI splitter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI splitter.In the left side I have a panel bar and in the right side I have the tabs.I want to increase  the splitter height dynamically with the tab content height ,can any one help me how to do this.
I have defined like

```
$("#splitter").kendoSplitter({            //To Display horizantal splitter
                        panes: [
                                            { collapsible: true, size: "50%" },
                                            { collapsible: true, size: "50%" }],
                     orientation: "horizontal",
      resize: function () {
        alert($("#splitter").find(".k-pane")[1].scrollHeight);
       //$("#splitter").css("height", $("#splitter").find(".k-pane")[1].scrollHeight);
     }
     });
```

but I am gettting "0" in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
var splitter = $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({            //To Display horizantal splitter
    panes: [
        { collapsible: true, size: "50%" },
        { collapsible: true, size: "50%" }],
    orientation: "horizontal",
    resize: function () {
        if(splitter) {
            alert(splitter.wrapper.height());
        }
        //you can also get the panes each on it's own.
        //check: console.log(splitter); to see what options are available           
    }
 }).data('kendoSplitter');
 splitter.trigger('resize');
```

Also look at the **[docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/splitter#configuration-panes)**.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snnmz/)

Comment: See my edited answer. The Splitter did a resize event as soon at it was declared. So the splitter variable wasn't actually filled by then. To circumvent the inital call, you can check if the variable is undefined or not. And if you want to have the inital resize event, then trigger it yourself.

Comment: hi,http://jsfiddle.net/XBFft/ In this my content height is more than splitter height in left pane,In that case I want to increase my splitter height inorder to elimanate the vertical scroll bar,how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle where your problem is visible. The one you provided doesn't show any weird behaviour or bugs.